# React testing library difference between snapshot and debug output

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have a very strange behavior, what can explain the fact that the output of the debug function, differs from the snapshot

```
  debug()
  expect(container).toMatchSnapshot()
```

The entire test function :

```
test('renders component with default args', async () => {

  const { container, debug, getByText } = render(<RolePopover />)

  fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button'))

  await waitFor(() => getByText('UI Designer'))
  
  debug()
  expect(container).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

The component perform a async call that's why i'm using the waitFor. The debug output contain the list with all the items fetched, but the snapshot not.

Thanks :)

Debug function output :

```
      <body
        style="padding-right: 0px; overflow: hidden;"
      >
        <div
          aria-hidden="true"
        >
          <div
            style="padding: 20px;"
          >
            <div
              class="sc-dlnjwi sc-hKFxyN pbobm jyUdcT"
            >
              <span
                class="sc-gtsrHT eqhufs"
                color="white"
              />
            </div>
            <button
              class="sc-fujyAs cFENAY"
              type="button"
            >
              <div
                class="sc-dlnjwi dIOGKH"
                display="flex"
                visibility="visible"
              >
                <span>
                  Pick a role
                </span>
              </div>
            </button>
            <div
              class="sc-bfmRie hyXwmM"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          class="MuiPopover-root sc-biHcxt hepaYp"
          role="presentation"
          style="position: fixed; z-index: 1300; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; top: 0px; left: 0px;"
        >
          <div
            aria-hidden="true"
            style="z-index: -1; position: fixed; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; top: 0px; left: 0px; background-color: transparent;"
          />
          <div
            data-test="sentinelStart"
            tabindex="0"
          />
          <div
            class="MuiPaper-root MuiPopover-paper paper MuiPaper-elevation8 MuiPaper-rounded"
            style="opacity: 1; transform: none; top: 16px; left: 16px;"
            tabindex="-1"
          >
            <div
              class="sc-dlnjwi bDyvvE"
              overflow="hidden"
            >
              <div
                class="sc-dlnjwi fSGxyX"
                display="flex"
              >
                <span
                  class="sc-iJCRrE gAUaF"
                >
                  Assign Role
                </span>
              </div>
              <div
                class="sc-dlnjwi jBCSWa"
              >
                <div
                  class="sc-dlnjwi lbGqZe"
                  display="flex"
                >
                  <div
                    class="sc-dlnjwi gjCrlq"
                    display="flex"
                  >
                    <div
                      class="sc-dlnjwi jjvWPi"
                      display="flex"
                    >
                      <span
                        class="sc-iJCRrE sc-dsXzNU hFzdJF fCIiLb"
                      >
                        Search a role
                      </span>
                      <input
                        class="sc-bTDOke fUXsvY"
                        type="text"
                        value=""
                      />
                    </div>
                    <fieldset
                      class="sc-eKYRIR TyfPs"
                    >
                      <legend
                        class="sc-hOPeYd hrYoc"
                      >
                        <span>
                          &
                        </span>
                      </legend>
                    </fieldset>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div
                class="sc-dlnjwi iEzfam"
                display="flex"
              >
                <div
                  class="sc-dlnjwi cMaOQq"
                  cursor="pointer"
                  display="flex"
                  opacity="1"
                >
                  <div
                    class="sc-dlnjwi clkcgn"
                  >
                    <span
                      class="sc-iJCRrE fPIdzb"
                    >
                      UI Designer
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div
                  class="sc-dlnjwi cMaOQq"
                  cursor="pointer"
                  display="flex"
                  opacity="1"
                >
                  <div
                    class="sc-dlnjwi clkcgn"
                  >
                    <span
                      class="sc-iJCRrE fPIdzb"
                    >
                      Dev
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div
                  class="sc-dlnjwi cMaOQq"
                  cursor="pointer"
                  display="flex"
                  opacity="1"
                >
                  <div
                    class="sc-dlnjwi clkcgn"
                  >
                    <span
                      class="sc-iJCRrE fPIdzb"
                    >
                      Marketing
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div
                  class="sc-dlnjwi cMaOQq"
                  cursor="pointer"
                  display="flex"
                  opacity="1"
                >
                  <div
                    class="sc-dlnjwi clkcgn"
                  >
                    <span
                      class="sc-iJCRrE fPIdzb"
                    >
                      Communication
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div
                  class="sc-dlnjwi cMaOQq"
                  cursor="pointer"
                  display="flex"
                  opacity="1"
                >
                  <div
                    class="sc-dlnjwi clkcgn"
                  >
                    <span
                      class="sc-iJCRrE fPIdzb"
                    >
                      R&D
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div
                  class="sc-dlnjwi cMaOQq"
                  cursor="pointer"
                  display="flex"
                  opacity="1"
                >
                  <div
                    class="sc-dlnjwi clkcgn"
                  >
                    <span
                      class="sc-iJCRrE fPIdzb"
                    >
                      Support
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div
                  class="sc-dlnjwi cMaOQq"
                  cursor="pointer"
                  display="flex"
                  opacity="1"
                >
                  <div
                    class="sc-dlnjwi clkcgn"
                  >
                    <span
                      class="sc-iJCRrE fPIdzb"
                    >
                      Role without members
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div
            data-test="sentinelEnd"
            tabindex="0"
          />
        </div>
      </body>
```

Snapshot ouput :

```
// Jest Snapshot v1

exports[`renders role popover with default args 1`] = `
.c2 {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 14rem;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.c0 {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #40577C;
}

.c4 {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  visibility: visible;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.c4 > * {
  margin-right: 10rem !important;
}

.c4 > *:last-child {
  margin-right: 0 !important;
}

.c1 {
  opacity: 0.9;
  word-break: break-word;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100000;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.c1 * {
  color: #ffffff !important;
}

.c3 {
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
  overflow: visible;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: inherit;
  font: inherit;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: normal;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: inherit;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: inherit;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 15rem;
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  display: -webkit-inline-flex;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  display: inline-flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 36rem;
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 14rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #0787EF;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.250,0.250,0.750,0.750);
  transition: background-color 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.250,0.250,0.750,0.750);
}

.c3::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.c3:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.c3:disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.c3 svg {
  stroke: #ffffff;
}

.c3:hover {
  background-color: #0787EF50;
}

.c3:disabled:hover {
  background-color: #0787EF;
}

.c5 {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 24px;
  z-index: 2000;
  right: 24px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
  -webkit-box-align: flex-end;
  -ms-flex-align: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
  -ms-flex-pack: end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.c5 > * {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.c5 > *:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

@media print {

}

<div
  aria-hidden="true"
>
  <div
    style="padding: 20px;"
  >
    <div
      class="c0 c1"
    >
      <span
        class="c2"
        color="white"
      />
    </div>
    <button
      class="c3"
      type="button"
    >
      <div
        class="c4"
        display="flex"
        visibility="visible"
      >
        <span>
          Pick a role
        </span>
      </div>
    </button>
    <div
      class="c5"
    />
  </div>
</div>
`;
```

Comment: Show the snapshot and what do you expect

Comment: @slideshowp2 i'v completed the post thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'v the answer ! The debug function display only the document, and the container it's only the component !

So this is working :

```
  expect(document.body).toMatchSnapshot()
```